# Cambiar video con SetAttribute

Tags: javascript, dom

**Resumen**

Estoy buscando la forma de cambiar el src de un video con javaScript de una forma en la que pueda reutilizar las funciones.

El codigo que les muestro no me funciona, no me funciona porque estoy trayendo el id del video de forma incorrecta:

**HTML**

```
 <video id="myVideo" name="helloButton" width="100%" height="550" controls="controls">
    <source src="img/videos/14-sep.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>

 <button onclick="cambiarVideo('myVideo', 'img/videos/365_365-0103_preview.mp4')">cambiarVideo</button>
```

**JS**

```
function cambiarVideo(id,Video){
      id.setAttribute("src", Video);
     }
```

Si alguien me puede echar una mano estaria muy agradecido

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@kvega, estás intentando acceder a un supuesto método (`setAttribute`) de la variable `id`, que es un `string`. Has de tomar el elemento video, tomar el source de ese vídeo, y después sí cambiar src:

```
  function cambiarVideo(id,Video){
    var obj_video = document.getElementById(id);
    var source = obj_video.getElementsByTagName('source')[0];
    
    source.setAttribute('src', Video);
  }
```